# $cordovaSocialSharing share() taking long time to show popup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am building one hybrid app using ionic. Where I am sharing pictures using ngCordova's $cordovaSocialSharing plugin. I am using the general share() function to share on any shareable platform. The feature is working fine but the main bottleneck is, it's taking about 5 seconds to show the list of shareable mediums. I have checked the plugin builder's GitHub, this problem is open in the issue list. So I want to know is there any other way to optimize this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the photo urls remote? If so the image has to be loaded and then manipulated by the plugin before share shows.